# How to verify in PolygonScan correctly?

Tags: solidity, remix, etherscan, hardhat, polygon

I am trying to verify a contract in Polygonscan.

I flatten my contract, remove the constructors, compile in REMIX IDE without erros with Petesburg EVM version using enabling optimization (200). The deployment from REMIX is correct to.

Then I select all the same in the PolygonScan form however, PolygonScan return the next when I tried to verify my single contract file:

> "Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI"
>
> But we were unable to locate a matching bytecode (err_code_2)
>
> ByteCode (what we are looking for)
>
> vs what we got
>
> We tried looking for a match from the list of compiled contract
> bytecode outputs (as listed below), but was unable to find an exact
> match.

Any ideas? I'm frustrated because I don't know what else to do
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mikko suggested I used HardHat to deploy and verify my contract and was correct.

I follow the next Polygon reference:

https://docs.polygon.technology/docs/develop/hardhat/

The last step was the effective to verify it without the "ByteCode and ABI" problems of PolygonScan:

```
npm install --save-dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan

npx hardhat verify --network matic 0x0000YourContractAddress
```

Answer (score 1):

Without having full access to your computer, it is not possible to tell what you are doing wrong.

If you use a smart contract development framework like [Brownie](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) to develop your smart contract, the framework automates this error-prone process and you are likely to have fewer problems in the future.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to deploy and verify with Hardhat and was correct